# Unable to perform activities on edge after opening the browser

Tags: selenium, microsoft-edge

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","F:\\VW_MU_Util\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
```

This is opening the edge browser however I cant go ahead since i'm getting error as:
org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones. Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

I tried to change the IE security settings but its opening the IE browser which i dont want to.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have initiate correct Edge Driver, as according to your OS version.

Ref link : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/

Steps :

[image: Steps]

Trace Build version:

[image: Build Version]

Download correct version of Driver:
[image: Download Correct Webdriver]

Once it finished, Verify it with demo project without any project capabilities. If it run successfully on sample project, It might cause browser capability with Selenium Browser.

Comment: Hi, ive crosschecked the versions. They are the same. I am able to open the script through chrome but not through edge.

Comment: Where you have defined driver path ? Please share more details.

Comment: i have downloaded the edge driver and copied it to a folder i.e. F:\\VW_MU_Util\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe i have also added the drivers to my project in eclipse and JRE library

Comment: I am not sure the method which you are approaching, Hope its the similar way as like Chrome, Firefox.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for all the help. There was an issue with Java I suppose. I installed Java 10 and it worked.